# Is someone also getting this error in Chrome 87.0.4280.88?

Tags: google-chrome

[image: Error]

"The information you’re about to submit is not secure
Because the site is using a connection that’s not completely secure, your information will be visible to others."

We have started receiving this error today. I thought that this is a certificate problem, but it's secure

[[image: secure connection]]

Also there no warnings and errors in console page

[image]

What do you advise to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem disappeared. I think they solved this problem, and now we don't have it)

Answer (score 2):

Same problem from today on chrome 87.0.4280.88.
Cert is ok and all assets are loaded over https.
My login forms are triggering this warning message, the form action url is relative so it's supposed to be sent over https too, don't know why this message is triggered...

Maybe try with absolute https action url.

[edit]
Check this tread -> https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/88331714?hl=en

For me it was the scheme on the location header when redirecting after successful login that was misconfigured on the reverse proxy, the app was sending back on http.

Fixed by adding these headers on reverse proxy conf on Nginx :

```
proxy_set_header         X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header         X-Forwarded-Port 443;
```

Make sur that your app is aware of these headers too.
For example in a symfony app -> https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment/proxies.html